# Messagebox comes up twice and emptying textbox with backspace gives error

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Thanks for your time on reading this.

My problem is that if i use `texbox.Clear();` that the messagebox shows 2 times.

Here is my code:

```
private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int val = 0;
    bool res = Int32.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out val);
    if (res == true && val > -1 && val < 101)
    {
        // add record
    }
    else
    {
        textBox3.Clear();
        MessageBox.Show("Please input 0 to 100 only.");
        return;
    }
}
```

AND

if i use this:

```
if (textBox3.Text == "")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Vul aub iets in", "Lege invoer",
    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
}
```

Then I will get a System.FormatException error for using this `straal = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);`

ALSO

When I am in the textbox and I enter a number and enter backspace the alert comes up.

Comment: If you clear the text it (usually) changes. to avoid the code in the chagrd event you will need a flag.

Comment: I would suggest, you use the Validate event instead of the TextChanged event.  This way you don't check the value until the user exits the textbox and changing the value in the event handler, won't fire the event again

Comment: And how do i do that, can we be more specific because i just started last week with this. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is `textBox3.Clear()`.  If there is text it is firing the `TextChanged` event again.

> I would suggest, you use the Validate event instead of the TextChanged event. This way you don't check the value until the user exits the textbox and changing the value in the event handler, won't fire the event again

*Correction - I should have said "Validating event".

Assuming you know how to assign an event handler to a specific event, you can use the same code with some small changes.  Something like this should work:

```
private void textBox3_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    int val = 0;
    bool res = Int32.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out val);
    if (res == true && val > -1 && val < 101)
    {
        // add record
        e.Cancel = false;
    }
    else
    {
        textBox3.Clear();
        e.Cancel = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Please input 0 to 100 only.");
    }
}
```

If you need help assigning the event handler, you can easily assign the handler and create a code stub, by finding the proper event in the events list, in the property grid, and double-clicking it.  Simply copy the contents of this method into the new one.

It looks like you're modifying the generated code directly.  This is not a good idea.  Use the method I described above to add the new event handler.

To delete the existing one, erase the method name saved with that event in the events list, then delete the code itself if necessary.

To get rid of the extra firings of the event handler, reset the textbox to a default acceptable value(`textBox3.Text = "0"`), instead of clearing it.

On a side note.  Have you considered using a NumericUpDown control instead?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i copied that code inside mine. and i changed `this.textBox3.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox3_TextChanged);` in `this.textBox3.Validating += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(this.textBox3_Validating);`. But now my other code is ignored about having a textbox when the input is blank with submit and if i want to close the window i will get the messagebox.show("please input 0 to....." How can i solve this?

Comment: If i close the window the message comes up only if the input fields are empty

Comment: Now i replaced `private void textBox3_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)` with `private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)` or should i have both?

Comment: @user9737826 - I added more to my answer for you.

Comment: `textBox3.Text = "0"`is a good solution, but i hoped on a code that ignores the textbox if i close the window for future projects. And the last thing that i want is that the messagebox shows only on submit and not if the input is empty because now when you maybe delete the zero and you want to edit the second input the messagebox comes up. Thanks for your effort and time

Comment: I think perhaps, since your requirements are getting more complicated, you might have to look at handling the KeyPress event as well and check each key as it's pressed to weed out wrong inputs.  Here's an [article](http://net-informations.com/q/faq/txtbox.html) which should help.